# current measurement in series-parallel solar panel array

Tags: measurement, solar-energy

I have a solar panel array wired in series-parallel. I know the voltages in a series network will be the average voltage, and the current in a parallel network will be the smallest contributing current. I'd like to monitor the output of each panel. I can't really do this without adding some circuitry. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B computer-on-a-card to monitor and control the installation. I'm thinking a relay associated with each panel and switched periodically to isolate each panel is the best I can hope for. I may be able to substitute semiconductor switches for electromechanical relays, but that is as simple as I think I can get. Any options I'm not aware of? Any alternatives? The array has panels in series to develop a 36vdc optimum voltage level for the charge controller used, and several such strings in parallel to increase the current.

Comment: Your 2nd sentence is reversed. Last sentence is correct.  You can make any array you want as as long as the load matches the source.  i.e. ~80%Voc for MP +/-x %

Comment: Thank you. I woke up in the middle of the night realizing I had made an error. For panels in series, the voltages add up. In parallel they are averaged. For panels in series, the total current is equal to the smallest, and in parallel, they add up. This isn't about me making any array I want. Please reread.